# Is there a name for leptons that are not neutrinos?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, standard-model, leptons

Is there a name for [leptons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepton) that are not neutrinos? Not sure if its exists, its not particularly easy to search for. Is there a name for the set of charged leptons (or leptons that are not neutrinos)?

This set includes;
$$ e^\pm \mu^\pm \tau^\pm$$

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepton) suggests _charged leptons_ or _electron-like leptons._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charged leptons. Neutrinos being the "Neutral leptons".

Comment: That's easy to remember :)